# How to avoid unnecessary fetching of data from database?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, jdbc

When executing the following JDBC code, I have in MySQL administrator observed several unnecessary database fetching activities.

```
public void tableData() {
    List<TaxAccountReportTableBean> tdata = new ArrayList<TaxAccountReportTableBean>();
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/inventory" + "", "root", "root");
    st = (Statement)con.createStatement(); 

    try {
        String qry = "SELECT taxno, region, taxname ,  tax, cf, cftax  FROM  Tax";
        System.out.println("-------->"+qry);
        rs = st.executeQuery(qry);

        while (rs.next()) {
            trtb = new TaxAccountReportTableBean();
            trtb.setTaxno(rs.getString(1));
            trtb.setRegion(rs.getString(2));
            trtb.setTaxname(rs.getString(3));
            trtb.setTaxpercent(rs.getString(4));
            trtb.setCfreq(rs.getString(5));
            trtb.setCftax(rs.getString(6));
            tdata.add(trtb);
        }

        rs.close();
        st.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I execute the query, I have observed in MySQL administrator that 10 queries are accessing database. Due to this unnecessary fetching the application performance is poor. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

---

**Update**: I have debugged the code and found that the unnecessary query fetching is occurring during connection creation process and not during getting data from query. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: So where did you put this method?

Answer (score 1):

In mysql you can use the `WHERE` condition to filter the data And can use the limit clause to get the specific rows data.

```
String qry = "SELECT taxno, region, taxname ,  tax, cf, cftax  FROM  Tax WHERE your_condition limit 10"
```

Your condition will be like this:

```
name LIKE "%abc%" //or you can use any thing based on your db structure.
```

Comment: The above mentioned table(ie Tax) contains only 6 records. I have tried your suggestion by limiting records to 2.Even though 10 queries are accessing database.

Comment: @Vasu if you have only 6 records in the table then there will not be any issue may be this will be taking time anywhere else. check by debug the code.

Comment: I have debugged the code and found that the unnecessary query fetching is occurring during connection creation process and not during  getting data from query.                                                 Is there is any suggestion to avoid this problem.

Comment: @Vasu Yes, use a connection pool. On the other hand: is it really causing a performance problem?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes,using the jdbc database access mechanism, for every data request to database a new connection is created.as creation creation process takes more time, application may face performance issue incase of more number of parallel database fetch activities.So i have implemented your suggestion(Connection pool) it's worked.